# Find literals in a java class programmatically

Tags: java, literals

I found out that Java Literals are syntactic representations of boolean, character, numeric, or string data.

My question is how to find literals in a java class programmatically?

If any one can provide me directions on how to achieve this ,that will be a great help.

Comment: How are you trying to get this information out, and what do you need to do with it?  It may be that the simplest way to do this is to plug into the Java compiler.

Comment: I have to find out classes in a java program with too many literals used, as a part of a project to detect code smells. can u explain how to use a compiler to achieve this programatically?

Comment: Compiler also replaces constant field access with the literal itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Java code parser, such as the ASTParser included in the Eclipse JDT tooling.

```
// Create the Java parser and parse the source code into an abstract syntax tree
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource(sourceCodeString.toCharArray());
CompilationUnit result = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
result.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
  public boolean visit(NumberLiteral n) {
    System.out.println("Found number literal in source code: " + n.getToken());
  }
});
```

You can then navigate the AST (abstract syntax tree) and extract what interests you.

Find longer examples [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html) or [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/).

You could also look at the source code of tools doing what you want to do, e.g. PMD or Findbugs (although the latter operates on compiled classes, not on source code).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,but im sorry, i need more help on this.

using the eg in the link you provided 

if in source file reading we have  int i = 9;  and in program
 
SimpleName name = node.getName();
this.names.add(name.getIdentifier());


 gets the variable name(i.e 'i'). but how am i suppose to know if the assigned value to the variable is a literal or not.

Comment: When the parser analyzes "int i = 9", it will add "9" as a literal to the abstract parse tree. Check the ASTVisitor class which you should use to traverse the parse result. It has methods such as "endVisit(NumberLiteral node)". I'll update the example a bit to illustrate this.